# Parsing a string formula to an integer result

Tags: string, delphi, math, formula

I'm doing some parsing work, too complex to get into details, but there's one simple thing I need to do (at least simple concept, maybe not simple answer). I might have a formula in a string such as the samples below. I need a function that will take a loosly-formatted formula string, parse it out, and calculate the result.

Sample:

`(10 / 2)+(10/30)`

`5+(10/30)`

`5+3`

`8`

Or:

`(12.5 - (0.5 * 5)) / 2`

`(12.5 - 2.5) / 2`

`10 / 2`

`5`

Rules:

- Spaces are to be ignored
- PEMDAS method must entirely apply
- Result shall be always a rounded Integer
- No variables will exist, already converted to numbers
- Decimal numbers might be part of the input

The existing parsing I already have working just gets one of these formula strings - but from there, I have no clue how to perform the actual calculations. What I'm doing specifically is doing a little line deliminated scripter to draw to a canvas, here's some sample script:

```
Var W 50
Var H 50
Pen Style Clear
Pen Color $000000
Pen Width 3
Brush Style Solid
Brush Color {FORM_COLOR}
Rect 0 0 {WIDTH} {HEIGHT}
Brush Color $501010
Ellipse @W @H 450 450
Brush Color $602020
Ellipse 100 100 400 400
Brush Color $703030
Ellipse 150 150 350 350
Brush Color $804040
Ellipse 200 200 300 300
EllipseG 200 200 300 300 6 2
Pen Style Solid
Pen Width 2
Pen Color {FONT_COLOR}
MoveTo 0 0
LineTo 500 500
MoveTo 0 500
LineTo 500 0
```

All that already works, but now I want to say for example...

```
Var W
Var H
Set W 50
Set H 50
Brush Color $602020
Ellipse(@W, @H, 500 - @W, 500 - @H
Set W 100
Set H 100
Brush Color $703030
Ellipse(@W, @H, 500 - @W, 500 - @H
Set W 150
Set H 150
Brush Color $804040
Ellipse(@W, @H, 500 - @W, 500 - @H
```

So the `500 - @W` I already convert it to `500 - 50` but now I need to send the string `500 - 50` into this function to get the result `450`.

**EDIT: Solved**

I'm using the `parser10` as recommended, and it works perfectly for what I need to do. Here's a sample snippet of my script code:

```
Var S 4
Var D @S
Var L 0
Var T 0
Var R {WIDTH}
Var B {HEIGHT}
Pen Style Clear
Pen Color $00000000
Pen Width 3
Brush Style Solid
Brush Color {FORM_COLOR}
Rect 0 0 {WIDTH} {HEIGHT}

Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00400000
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00501010
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00602020
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00703030
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00804040
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00905050
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
Set D @D+@S
Brush Color $00FB6060
Ellipse @L+@D @T+@D @R-(@D*2) @B-(@D*2)
```

Anything starting with an @ is a variable, which I do a `StringReplace()` to convert all those based on what was declared in the `Var` section.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to write the expression parser yourself, or do you want to use 3rd party code?

Comment: I've tried to use 3rd party parsing code, that stuff's a ridiculous mess. I'm sure there's plenty of people who have already made such a formula parser at least - I have everything else done - except for calculating these formulas, which I have nothing yet but an empty function shell `Calc(const Formula: String): Integer;`

Comment: If I had a time machine, I could go back to 1985 and get it for you!  I know I made one of these as homework once.

Comment: @ChrisThornton: If you had a time machine, you wouldn't be wasting away your time on the internet for this kinda chitter chatter :P

Comment: This is probably not the simplest method, but this could be solved using a state machine and regular expressions, assuming your math operators are limited

Comment: Does JvExprParser from JEDI really not get the job done for you. I always assumed that was a simple plug and play job.

Comment: I mean 'it's really complex' as in I have over 300 lines into it, I'm not going to post all that here - just I have it down to a formula string - I need just that string to be parsed and calculated.

Comment: [Parser10](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/d10free/parser10.zip) is fairly a simple math parser. See if it suits you, or expand its functionallity.

Comment: try the [JvInterpreter](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/JvInterpreter.htm) component which is part of the JVCL.

Comment: Was getting assembly debug level exception with Parser 10's demo in XE5. Tried Cindy's cyMathParser, works like a charm. `cyMathParser1.Expression := edt1.Text;
    cyMathParser1.Parse();    edt2.Text := FloatToStr(cyMathParser1.ParserResult);` Also exposes an onBeforeParse() which might be helpful to trim spaces etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parser10](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/d10free/parser10.zip), written originally by Renate Schaaf for Delphi 1 and later upgraded to Delphi2 and 3 by Alin Flaider and Stefan Hoffmeister, is a fairly simple math parser. It will do the job for simple expressions and can serve as a boilerplate for more complex work.

It is not built for speed though.

Update :

Hallvard Vassbotn made an update of Parser10 and added some documentation. Load it from [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/15974).

Answer (score 0):

List of Parsers, Mathematical Expression Evaluators, Calculators: [here](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/Parsers.htm)

[Edit]
Or a TBindExpression in Delphi XE2, not sure if its apply PEMDAS

Comment: Its working fine for me, but here's the link: http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/Parsers.htm

Comment: They work now for me, must have been down at that time.