# How to read in a user defined math function

Tags: function, math, pascal

I'm trying to build a program in Pascal to differentiate mathematical functions. It's working very well (calculate min/max, symmetry, drawing the graph, etc.) but I have to put the functions (i.e. x^3+3x+2) into the source code like this:

```
function f(x : real): real;
begin 
   f := x * x * x + 3 * x + 2;
end;
```

Though, I want the user to define the function to differentiate. Obviosly the readln function does not help.
Somebody told me the only solution would be a specific parser. But it's very difficult, and I don't know how to do it.
My idea would be to extract the function into a *.txt file for example so that it could be changed easily. Is that possible?
Can somebody show me a parser which could solve this problem or have anybody some other great solution?
I would really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: It's not necessary to put the same info in your title that you're putting in the tags. The tag system here works very well, and trying to help it by adding it in the subject just causes clutter. Please don't do so. Thanks.

Comment: Some information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326258/mathematical-expression-parser-in-delphi

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, I'm new here :)

Comment: You want [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).

Comment: Parser10, by Renate Schaaf and updated by Hallvard Vassbotn, is a mathematical parser that would work in your case. See [`Parsing a string formula to an integer result`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228855/576719) for more details.

Comment: If you use Free Pascal see unit symbolic integrated with the distribution. It also does (symbolic) differentiation.

Comment: you can first ask for the order of the function, and then for the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Free Pascal ships with the [symbolic](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/packages/symbolic/) package, which has both a parser and evaluator for mathematical expressions. You can probably use this as a starting point. See the [documentation](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/packages/symbolic/doc/symbolic.txt?revision=10064&view=markup) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are also a number of parsers/evalutaors on [SWAG](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/):

- **[EQUATE.PAS](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0003.PAS.html)** (short, clean evaluator)
- [PARSMATH.PAS](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0009.PAS.html) (very short example code)
- [Math Parsing Unit](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0032.PAS.html) (undocumented, kind of messy)
- [Math Evaluations](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0048.PAS.html) (Somewhat cryptic.)
- **[Nice Expression Parser](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0050.PAS.html)** (Small, seems well done.)
- [Expression Evaluator](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0053.PAS.html) (Messier, includes trig functions.)
- [Math Expression Evaluator](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0060.PAS.html) (not well documented)
- [Equation Parser](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0061.PAS.html) (converts equations to arrays of coefficients)
- **[Text Formula Parser](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/MATH/0073.PAS.html)** (fairly complete parser/evaluator unit)

I bolded the ones I thought were the most useful. I don't think any of them are as complete as the symbolic package in my other answer, but they might be worth reading if you need help.

(All of this is fairly old code. Unless otherwise stated, the rule with SWAG is to treat this stuff as having a new-style BSD license)