# Delphi: interpreter for string expression with operators

Tags: delphi, eval

i want evaluate at runtime some string expression like:

```
((foo = true) or (bar <> 'test')) and (baz >= 1)
```

The string are inputted by user. The user can create a rule by coupling a property choised from a set (eg. `foo`, `bar`, `baz`), inputting the target value to evaluate (`string`, `number` and `boolean`) and choising the operator (`=`, `<>`, `>`, `<`), eg.:

```
| Id | Property | Operator | Value  |   Expression                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $1 |   foo    |    =     |  true  | (foo = true)                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $2 |    bar   |    <>    | 'test' | (bar <> 'test')                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $3 |    baz   |    >=    |   1    | (baz >= 1)                                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the single rule can be coupled and nested in child/parent rule by choosing an operator like `and`, `or`, eg.:

```
| Id | Property | Operator | Value  |   Expression                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $1 |   foo    |    =     |  true  | (foo = true)                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $2 |    bar   |    <>    | 'test' | (bar <> 'test')                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $3 |    baz   |    >=    |   1    | (baz >= 1)                                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $4 |    $1    |    or    |  $2    | ((foo = true) or (bar <> 'test'))                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| $5 |    $4    |   and    |  $3    | ((foo = true) or (bar <> 'test')) and (baz >= 1)    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in peseudo code, the idea is:

```
aExpressionEngine := TExpressionEngine.Create;
try
    // Adds to the evaluation scope all the properties with the
    // inputted value. AddToScope accept string, variant
    aExpressionEngine.AddToScope('foo', false);
    aExpressionEngine.AddToScope('bar', 'qux');
    aExpressionEngine.AddToScope('baz', 10);

    // evaluate the expression, the result is always a boolean
    Result := aExpressionEngine.eval('(((foo = true) or (bar <> ''test'')) and (baz >= 1))');
finally
    aExpressionEngine.free;
end;
```

in this pseudo code example, the expression to evaluate become (after replacing the properties with the scope value):

```
(((false = true) or ('qux' <> 'test')) and (10 >= 1)) // TRUE
```

by googling, i have found a bit of library for evaluate math expression, but nothing for logical condition evaluating.

Has delphi something for evaluate string expression?

Comment: If the strings are not too large, you may be able to replace them with long integers.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette yes, good idea! thanks! but if exists an eval() way it's better!

Comment: These languages are interpreted, and they simply pass the condition to be evaluated through their interpreter.  Delphi is a compiled language, and has no interpreter. Of course you could write an interpreter for simple expressions, but I don't think there is an existing one. It would be similar to the ones that evaluate arithmetic expressions, but it would have to be extended to evaluate string expressions. Not really a "simple operator". And `('baz' <> 0)` would be invalid anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you could build such an expression using Variants. It would still be some work. It would have to parse and interpret such expressions, in other words, you would be building a simple interpreter.

Comment: How will you evaluate this? Where will you get the variables from?

Comment: One also wonders how you imagine comparison of string and integer to work

Comment: Comparate string and integer it's a my mistake into the example.

Comment: Maybe [TBindingExpression](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Bindings.Expression.TBindingExpression).

Comment: Have you checked this out ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572796/best-algorithm-for-evaluating-a-mathematical-expression I know the title says c#, but the accepted answer is for Delphi.

Comment: Maybe overkill, but perhaps what you want is... http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx

Comment: All I can say is DWScript. That is not an answer, but an option. I've used it in the past to store instructions for drawing graphics. So that the user can create their own script file to paint to a canvas. Can also be used for general expressions too.

Comment: @David Those don't look like variables. They look like value types.

Comment: Delphi does indeed have the ability to compile and evaluate expressions- see https://theroadtodelphi.com/2012/07/06/a-quick-guide-to-evaluate-and-compile-expressions-using-the-livebindings-expression-evaluator/ and this code by Nick Hodges - https://bitbucket.org/NickHodges/nickdemocode/src/842eb3fc74d7/SampleExpressionEvaluator.dpr?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @Victoria thanks, i have also found this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650447/building-and-evaluating-expressions-using-delphi-rtti/16651657#16651657

Comment: thanks all for the suggestions, after some downvotes i have totally update my question with more details and a pratical example.

Comment: Asking for external sources is off topic here. A brief search found these examples: [Components|Science|Expressions](http://torry.net/pages.php?id=307).