# I want to complete this calculator program . Calculation begins when user enters =

Tags: pascal

```
Program calculator;
Var
N : integer ;
Op : char;
Begin
Repeat
  Writeln('Enter a number : ');
  Readln(N);
  Writeln('Enter an operator : ');
  Readln(Op);
Until ( Op = '=');
```

Then what should i do next to make the calculation 
    and show it on the screen

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, it isn't a tutorial site, so your q is not a good fit here.  Are you looking for something which will input two numbers and an operator and evaluate the result, or something which will evaluate an arbitrarily complex expression?  There is a **big** difference ...  If the former, read up on the `Case` statement, which you can use to determine what evaluation is performed, depending on the operator.

Comment: Btw, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326258/mathematical-expression-parser-in-delphi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mathematical expression parser in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326258/mathematical-expression-parser-in-delphi)

Comment: This will require library for expression evaluation. It would be helpful if you specified which compiler and version you use.