# Delphi, evaluate formula string

Tags: algorithm, delphi, math, parsing, formula

#### Duplicate

> - [Best algorithm for evaluating a mathematical expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572796/best-algorithm-for-evaluating-a-mathematical-expression)
> - [mathematical expression parser in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326258/mathematical-expression-parser-in-delphi)

I need a program in Delphi that get one variable equation from Edit1 such as  `"F(x)=4*X+2*log(x)+4*power(X,2)"`
and get X value variable from Edit2 then show the result F(X) in Edit3.  Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572796/best-algorithm-for-evaluating-a-mathematical-expression and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326258/1326307#1326307

Answer (score 5):

You can also check out [JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/), which comes with an expression evaluator in the file [JclExprEval.pas](http://jcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jcl/trunk/jcl/source/common/JclExprEval.pas?view=markup). It's free and open source.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to have a look at this component - TbcParser.

https://www.mathparsers.com/formula-parser-for-delphi/

This component has source code included.

Comment: Thank you, replaced it with a working link

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/Parsers.htm

Also, if you have JEDI and/or FastReport libraries installed you can use their parsers. We use TParser10 from http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/15974 which is one of the fastest available if not **the** fastest. It is freeware and work flawlessly up to D2007. I heard that it works also in D2009. Not tested yet though.

Comment: I'm the author of one of the packages on that list, Symbolic.

Note that the URL there goes to the original  (FPC) package. The Delphi package is at http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/symbolicdelphi.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write an own implementation and not use a ready to use library this will take you some time to do. Just search for "formula parser". I would start with a tokenizer and then build a parse tree from the tokens.

Answer (score -1):

It STRONGLY depdends on your decimal separator. Use StrToFloat or in newewr versions of Delphi - TryStrToFloat.