# How can I parse a numeric operation containing +,-,*,/ and parentheses and return the result?

Tags: delphi, parsing, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best algorithm for evaluating a mathematical expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572796/best-algorithm-for-evaluating-a-mathematical-expression)

I mean like when you enter this in Delphi:

```
var i : integer;
begin
  i=5 + 5 + (2 * (3 + 2)) + (1 * 4 + (1 - 3))
end;
```

But I want a command that works in this way:

```
var i : integer; s:string;
begin
  s:='5 + 5 + (2 * (3 + 2)) + (1 * 4 + (1 - 3))';
  i:=ParseInt(s);
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a basic problem in compiler/interpreter methods, though you don't need the full tool kit. Check [Learning to write a compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/) for an exhaustive list of resource. I'd like to recomend the Crenshaw tutorial for this problem, though you will have to adapt the compiler to a interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement this yourself, have a look at [recursive descent parses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) and the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of free or inexpensive Math Parser components available for Delphi:

[Foreval](http://sourceforge.net/projects/foreval/) is open source, available as a DLL or delphi component.

[TbcParser](http://www.bestcode.com/html/tbcparser.html) is $19.95 with source code.